# Minted package :: Package minted Error: Missing Pygments output

Tags: minted, pygments

My tags are follows:

```
\documentclass[]{book}
\usepackage[many,documentation]{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{skins, breakable, minted}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{minted}
\usemintedstyle[jasonagent]{jacamo}
\usemintedstyle[jacamoproject]{jacamo}
\usemintedstyle[java]{manni}
\usemintedstyle[xml]{manni}
\setminted{fontsize=\small}


\begin{document}


\inputminted{jacamoproject}{chapter3/code/org_hw3/sag_hw.jcm}

\end{document}
```

The content of the `sag_hw.jcm` follow as:

```
mas sag_hw {                 // the MAS is identified by sag_hw
  agent bob: hwa.asl {  // initial plans for bob are in hwa.asl
    goals: say("Hello World")           // initial goal for bob
  }
}
```

I am running the file through `PDFLaTeX --shell-escape filename.tex`, then I got the below error:

```
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\inputenc.sty"
Package: inputenc 2015/03/17 v1.2c Input encoding file
\inpenc@prehook=\toks42
\inpenc@posthook=\toks43
)
\AtBeginShipoutBox=\box78
Package hyperref Info: Link coloring OFF on input line 13.

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\hyperref\nameref.sty"
Package: nameref 2016/05/21 v2.44 Cross-referencing by name of section

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\gettitlestring.sty"
Package: gettitlestring 2016/05/16 v1.5 Cleanup title references (HO)
)
\c@section@level=\count275
)
LaTeX Info: Redefining \ref on input line 13.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \pageref on input line 13.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \nameref on input line 13.

(test.out) (test.out)
\@outlinefile=\write9
\openout9 = `test.out'.

Package marginnote Info: \pdfoutput not 0 or unimportant and
(marginnote)             \pdflastxpos or \lastxpos available.
(marginnote)             Extended position detection mode activated.
 (_minted-test/default-pyg-prefix.pygstyle)
(_minted-test/jacamo.pygstyle)
runsystem(pygmentize -l jacamoproject -f latex -P commandprefix=PYG -F tokenmer
ge -o _minted-test/867A5D77E073C9C3542991A9CE2FD115.pygtex chapter3/code/org_hw
3/sag_hw.jcm)...executed.



! Package minted Error: Missing Pygments output; \inputminted was
probably given a file that does not exist--otherwise, you may need 
the outputdir package option, or may be using an incompatible build tool,
or may be using the kpsewhich option without having PowerShell installed,
or may be using frozencache with a missing file.

See the minted package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.16 ...project}{chapter3/code/org_hw3/sag_hw.jcm}

? x

Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 31918 strings out of 493329
 646869 string characters out of 3139066
 750960 words of memory out of 3000000
 35000 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+200000
 4498 words of font info for 17 fonts, out of 3000000 for 9000
 1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 60i,1n,93p,10505b,275s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,50000s
No pages of output.

pdfTeX warning: pdflatex: dangling objects discarded, no output file produced.

PDF statistics:
 41 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)
 0 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 500000)
 145 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 10000000)
```

I am using MikTeX 2.9 on Windows7 system. I installed `Python` and `pygmentize`

Please advise what went wrong in my code...

**EDIT**

After updating the package `minted` and `Python` and `Pygmentize`, I received the error only for the language `\inputminted{jasonagent}{test.asl}` only, any advise plase...

```
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\hyperref\nameref.sty"
Package: nameref 2016/05/21 v2.44 Cross-referencing by name of section

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\gettitlestring.sty"
Package: gettitlestring 2016/05/16 v1.5 Cleanup title references (HO)
)
\c@section@level=\count275
)
LaTeX Info: Redefining \ref on input line 14.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \pageref on input line 14.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \nameref on input line 14.

(test.out) (test.out)
\@outlinefile=\write9
\openout9 = `test.out'.

Package marginnote Info: \pdfoutput not 0 or unimportant and
(marginnote)             \pdflastxpos or \lastxpos available.
(marginnote)             Extended position detection mode activated.
 (_minted-test/default-pyg-prefix.pygstyle)
(_minted-test/jacamo.pygstyle)
runsystem(pygmentize -l jasonagent -f latex -P commandprefix=PYG -F tokenmerge 
-o _minted-test/C5DCCD1D20214F384C955C5C6642EE150A20182925029C5A43F21CEF965EC88
9.pygtex test.asl)...executed.



! Package minted Error: Missing Pygments output; \inputminted was
probably given a file that does not exist--otherwise, you may need 
the outputdir package option, or may be using an incompatible build tool,
or may be using frozencache with a missing file.

See the minted package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.19 \inputminted{jasonagent}{test.asl}

? x

Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 31968 strings out of 493329
 648759 string characters out of 3139066
 755772 words of memory out of 3000000
 35051 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+200000
 4498 words of font info for 17 fonts, out of 3000000 for 9000
 1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 60i,1n,93p,10484b,275s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,50000s
No pages of output.

pdfTeX warning: pdflatex: dangling objects discarded, no output file produced.

PDF statistics:
 41 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)
 0 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 500000)
 145 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 10000000)
```

Comment: check what the output says before the error message.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer sorry, complete `log` file placed...

Comment: *before* the error message not *behind*.

Comment: your system doesn't look up-to-date. At least inputenc and nameref are older then my versions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above said issue solved if I run the file in `Mac` system with the combination of `Docker + PDFLaTeX`...Thanks to all...